# How do I fix the error "Non static variable being referenced from static content"?

Tags: java

I have this project due in my intro to programming (java) course. Its supposed to create a string instrument using methods, and play the instrument etc.. I've already done this project once in C#, but for what ever reason I can't seem to get it to work in java. I keep getting an error that "non static variable cannont be referenced from static content. I've searched on here, and so far non of the solutions work for me. Please help. Thanks!!

`    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

```
package egreenhornfinal;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Eddie
 */
 public class EGreenhornFinal {


class Guitar
{


    boolean isTuned; //Guitar starts off not tuned
    boolean isPlaying; //Guitar is not playing at start
    boolean isBroken; //Guitar has broken a string
    boolean isFixed; //Broken String has been fixed
    boolean isNotPlaying; //Guitar has stopped playing
    boolean songOver; //The song is over now.

    //array for Guitar strings
    char[] GuitarStrings = { 'e', 'A', 'D', 'G', 'B', 'E' };
    private int numberofStrings = 6;

    //default Guitar object
    public Guitar()
    {
        isTuned = false;
        isPlaying = false;
        isBroken = false;
        isFixed = false;
        isNotPlaying = false;
        songOver = false;

        System.out.println("The Guitar is not playing, and it is not tuned. All Strings are intact.\n");
        }
    public Guitar(boolean T, boolean P)
    {
        isTuned = T;
        isPlaying = P;
    }
    public boolean playGuitar()
    {
        System.out.println("The Guitar is playing!\n");
        return isPlaying = true;
    }
    public boolean stopPlaying()
    {
        System.out.println("The Guitar has stopped playing.\n");
        return isNotPlaying = true;
    }
    public boolean tuneGuitar()
    {
        System.out.println("The Guitar is being tuned!\n");
        return isTuned = true;
    }
    public boolean brokenString()
    {
        System.out.println("One of the strings was too tight, it has broken!\n");
        return isBroken = true;
    }
    public boolean fixedString()
    {
        System.out.println("The broken string has been fixed, the guitar is now playing again.\n");
        return isFixed = true;
    }
    public boolean EndOfSong()
    {
        System.out.println("The Guitar has stopped playing because the song is over.\n");
        return songOver = true;
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String WantToPlay = "Y";
        do
        {


            Guitar MyGuitar = new Guitar();
            //Error-- Non static variable being referenced from static content??


            boolean varIsTuned = false;
            varIsTuned = MyGuitar.tuneGuitar();

            boolean varIsPlaying = false;
            varIsPlaying = MyGuitar.playGuitar();

            boolean varIsNotPlaying = true;
            varIsNotPlaying = MyGuitar.stopPlaying();

            boolean varIsBroken = false;
            varIsBroken = MyGuitar.brokenString();

            boolean varIsFixed = false;
            varIsFixed = MyGuitar.fixedString();

            boolean varsongOver = false;
            varsongOver = MyGuitar.EndOfSong();

         System.out.println("Would you like to play the Guitar again? (enter Y for yes, and N for no)");
         Scanner inUsr = new Scanner(System.in);
         WantToPlay = inUsr.nextLine();



        }


        while (WantToPlay == "Y");
        }

}


`
```

Comment: Look at all those links over on the right hand side :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. please search for your issue before posting a new question that has been asked several times before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context?rq=1

Comment: i answered a question exactly like this the other day. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/23429937/217324

Comment: If those links had been helpful I wouldn't have needed to ask my question....

Comment: @user3620597: read the link i added, it's about the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the inner class as static too. Otherwise it is non-static (you can access the outer this-pointer from a non-static inner class).